# Are there any static binary rewriting tools？

Tags: binary-analysis, static-analysis, instrumentation

My goal is to modify some instructions and make some instrumentation in ELF executables or libraries(For example, modifying all memory writes instructions). Since there're so many instructions, I want to find them automatically and apply some modification. Are there any tools that I can leverage?

Comment: @w s I mean static instrumentation, and I want to modify elf files.

Comment: does it *have* to be static? there are many  tools for dynamic instrumentation, why do you need specifically binary rewriting?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I want to change ELF files, and run them without any tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just extracted the following list during my research of this paper:

> **"Reassembleable Disassembling"** Shuai Wang, Pei Wang, and Dinghao Wu,
>   The Pennsylvania State University

The following list consits of all mentioned tools (dynamic and static), perhaps there is something useful:

---

**UROBOROS** *(Static, x86/x64 ELF)*

So the paper itself introduces UROBOROS. I think it's one of the best options for you:

https://github.com/s3team/uroboros

> **"Reassembleable Disassembling"** Shuai Wang, Pei Wang, and Dinghao Wu,
>   The Pennsylvania State University
>
> In this paper, we present UROBOROS, a tool that can disassemble
>   executables to the extent that the gener- ated code can be assembled
>   back to working binaries without manual effort. [...]
>
> We have implemented a prototype of UROBOROS in OCaml and Python, with
>   a total of 13,209 lines of code. Our prototype works for both x86 and
>   x64 ELF binaries. [...]
>
> We have presented UROBOROS, a tool that can disassem- ble stripped
>   binaries and produce reassembleable assem- bly code in a fully
>   automated manner. We call this tech- nique reassembleable
>   disassembling and have developed a prototype called UROBOROS. Our
>   experiments show that reassembled programs incur negligible execution
>   overhead, and thus UROBOROS can be potentially used as a foundation
>   for binary-based software retrofitting.

---

**Dyninst [10, 20]** *(Static+Dynamic)*

> BUCK, B., AND HOLLINGSWORTH, J. K. An API for runtime code patching.
>   Int. J. High Perform. Comput. Appl. 14, 4 (2000), 317–329.

---

**Vulcan [16]** *(Static, binaries compiled by special compilers, not stripped)*

> EDWARDS, A., VO, H., SRIVASTAVA, A., AND SRIVASTAVA, A. Vulcan binary
>   transformation in a distributed environment. Tech. Rep.
>   MSR-TR-2001-50, Microsoft Research, 2001.

---

**Alto [35]** *(Static, binaries compiled by special compilers, not stripped)*

> MUTH, R., DEBRAY, S. K., WATTERSON, S., AND DE BOSS- CHERE, K. Alto: A
>   link-time optimizer for the Compaq Alpha. Softw. Pract. Exper. 31, 1
>   (2001), 67–101.

---

**Diablo [13]** *(Static, binaries compiled by special compilers, not stripped)*

> DE SUTTER, B., DE BUS, B., AND DE BOSSCHERE, K. Link- time binary
>   rewriting techniques for program compaction. ACM Trans. Program. Lang.
>   Syst. 27, 5 (2005), 882–945.

---

**SecondWrite [3]** *(Static)*

> ANAND, K., SMITHSON, M., ELWAZEER, K., KOTHA, A., GRUEN, J., GILES,
>   N., AND BARUA, R. A compiler-level inter- mediate representation based
>   binary analysis and rewriting sys- tem. In Proceedings of the 8th ACM
>   European Conference on Computer Systems (2013), ACM, pp. 295–308.

---

**Pin [31]** *(Dynamic)*

> LUK, C.-K., COHN, R., MUTH, R., PATIL, H., KLAUSER, A., LOWNEY, G.,
>   WALLACE, S., REDDI, V. J., AND HAZELWOOD, K. Pin: Building customized
>   program analysis tools with dy- namic instrumentation. In Proceedings
>   of the 2005 ACM SIG- PLAN Conference on Programming Language Design
>   and Im- plementation (2005), ACM, pp. 190–200.

---

**DynamoRIO [7]** *(Dynamic)*

> BRUENING, D. L. Efficient, transparent, and comprehensive runtime code
>   manipulation. PhD thesis, Massachusetts Institute of Technology, 2004.

---

**miasm2**

> Miasm is a free and open source (GPLv2) reverse engineering framework.
>   Miasm aims to analyze / modify / generate binary programs.
>   https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm

---

**VxStripper** *(dynamic)*

> Josse, Sébastien. "Malware Dynamic Recompilation." System Sciences
>   (HICSS), 2014 47th Hawaii International Conference on. IEEE, 2014.

Comment: [Miasm2](https://github.com/cea-sec/miasm) is also able to rewrite binary code.

Comment: I added miasm2 and VxStripper.

Comment: The authors have extended their work, UROBOROS, and it is also able to rewrite binary code.

Comment: I read the paper yesterday and I will add it to my answer. I think it's probably a good option for you.